# eloquent search with two tables not working exactly?

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent

```js
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "MD. AZMAL FUAD",
    "roll": 19440801,
    "registration_no": 0,
    "technology_id": 1,
    "session_id": 4,
    "semester": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-15 10:38:59",
    "attendance": [{
        "id": 1,
        "student_id": 1,
        "semester": 2,
        "attendance_percentage": null,
        "status": 0,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }]
}
```

This is my result after eloquent Search. search code is -

```
$data = Student::with('attendance')->where('semester',1)->get();
        return $data;
```

now my question is I've joined attendance table and both table has '**semester**' column, how can I search semester from 2nd table only. In that search, It'll skip checking first table.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you only want students who have attendence relations with semester 1 ? or you want all students but only want the attendence loaded if it has semester 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$data = Student::with(['attendance' => function($q){
   $q->where('semester',1);
}])->get();

return $data;
```

Or you can use `whereHas` to check for `Relationship existence`

```
$data = Student::whereHas('attendance', function($q){
    $q->where('semester', 1); })->get();

  return $data;
```

if you want to pass dynamic data you can use `use method` for this:

```
$semester = $request->session_year;

$data = Student::with(['attendance' => function($q) use ($semester){
       $q->where('semester',$semester);
    }])->get();

    return $data;
```

Using `whereHas`

```
 $semester = $request->session_year;

 $data = Student::whereHas('attendance', function($q) use ($semester){
        $q->where('semester', $semester); })->get();

      return $data;
```

for more information you can visit [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Thanks

Comment: my question is , when I want to put dynamic value inside functions as this_ 

`code`
$users = Student::with('attendance')->whereHas('attendance', function($query){
            $query->where('semester', 2);
        })->where(['technology_id' => $request->technology,'session_id' => $request->session_year])->get();
`code`

I want to put dynamic value inside functions instead of 2. how can I do this?

Comment: instead of 1 , how can I use dynamic data ( as $request->semester) inside function ?

Comment: @Mdimran As your query pass dynamic `$request->semester`. I have updated my answer. Check it

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code:
You need to check both `with` and `whereHas()`.

As your concern pass dynamic data for that use `use()` method.

```
$users = Student::with('attendance')->whereHas('attendance', function($q) use ($request->semester) {
    $q->where('semester', $request->semester);
})->get();
```